# Ltspice Full-wave rectified signal issue

Tags: ltspice, bridge-rectifier

I have done a simple simulation with Ltspice with a bridge diode rectifier as shown with the picture below. However I have observed an issue in the shape of the output voltage and not the current output. Has anyone get same issue as me ? I thank you to tell me how can I resolve such issue.

[image]

Comment: Move your ground to the DC negative node.

Comment: @jonk: I thank you very much for your answer. It resolves my issue. Can you give me more details ? Why with the first position of ground it does'nt work correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: You set your ground on an AC leg, then tried to look at a DC output referenced to that AC ground. It's almost always confusing when you do that. It's not wrong, but it will require head-twisting and lots of explanation before you understand it's just fine. Moving the ground to the DC reference makes the DC side make more sense.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. It's sufficient for me as answer.

Comment: Good. I see you have your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

@jonk: I thank you very much for your answer.
I Have moved the ground to the DC negative node.  That's how I have resolved my issue.